# How do I get the value of CharField() during instansiation?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to pass model fields values as arguments to another field.

`trademark_class.get_default()` method is close to what I want, but I do not want solely the default value.

I am also unable to use `__dict__.['trademark_class']` in this case as I need a 'this' reference to the class and do not know the proper way to achieve that for this case.

```py
class Form_33_Model(models.Model):
    trademark_number = models.CharField(default='default number', max_length=30)
    trademark_class = models.CharField(default='default class', max_length=30)
    trademark_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    html = models.TextField(default=Form33StringClass(trademark_class=trademark_class.get_default(),
                                                    trademark_number=trademark_number.get_default()).form_33_string)
```

Instead of the default value only, I would like to get either the actual value of the Charfield or its default value.

So something like : `trademark_class.get_current_value_or_default()` would be ideal for what I want.

Below is my Form33StringClass.py

```py
import datetime


class Form33StringClass():
    def __init__(self, trademark_number, trademark_class):
        self.trademark_number = trademark_number
        self.trademark_class = trademark_class
        self.day = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A") + " " + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d")
        self.month = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%B")
        self.year = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y")
        self.form_33_string = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Trade Marks Act</title>
        <style>
            .letter_margin {
                margin: auto 25%;
                line-height: 25px;
            }
            header{
                text-align: center;
            }
            .intro {
                text-align: center;
                font-style: italic;
            }
            .request{

            }
            .office_address{
                width: 50%;
                margin-left: 10%;
            }
            .address_row{
                display: flex;
                align-items: baseline;
            }

            .re-address_row{
                /* float: right; */
                display: flex;
                justify-content: flex-end;
            }
            .re_address{
                width: 60%;

            }
            .to_registrar{
                display: flex;
                align-items: baseline;
            }

            .registrar_paragraph {
                margin-left: 10%;
            }

            .underlined{
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
            .trademark_class{

            }
            .trademark_number{

            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <header>
                    <h1>TRADE MARKS ACT</h1>
                    <h2>FORM 33</h2>
                </header>
            </tr>
            <tr >
                <div class="intro letter_margin">
                    <p>
                        Form of Request to the Registrar by a Registered Proprietor or a Registered User of a Trade Mark, or a person  about  to be so registered, to enter, alter, or substitute an Address  for  service  as  part  of  his  Registration (Regulations 15, 82. 86 and 102)
                    </p>
                </div>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <div class="request letter_margin">
                    <p >

                        Request is made by: <br><br>


                        A company incorporated in <br>

                        Carrying on business as manufacturers and merchants at:<br><br><br>


                        who is about to be registered as/who is the Registered Proprietor of Trade Mark(s)<br> No <span class="underlined trademark_number"> """+ trademark_number +"""</span> registered in Class(es) <span class="underlined trademark_class"> """+trademark_class+"""</span> <br>

                        for the inclusion/addition/alteration/substitution of an address for service in Nigeria in or to <br> the entry thereof so that the address for service in Nigeria may read:
                    </p>
                </div>
            </tr>

            ....

    </body>
</html>


"""
```

when a new Form_33_Model.objects.create(trademark_class, trademark_number) is created :

```
{
  trademark_class : "class foo",
  trademark_number : "number bar",
  html : "<html>...
    <tag> class foo </tag> 
    <tag> number bar </tag>
...
</html>"
}
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of a use case of this? I don't understand why `object.trademark_class` doesn't achieve this.

Comment: This is entirely the wrong approach. You should do this in the form.

Comment: Are you trying to get the default without instantiating the object?  If so, then `Form_33_Model._meta.get_field('trademark_class')` may be what you're looking for.

Comment: @TimTisdall I do want something like this (and have achieved that in the interactive  shell) , but I do not know how to give that Form_33_Model reference within my class. I can't simply call `self._meta.get_field('field_name')` as self can only be called from within a method.

Comment: This seems like it may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @DanielRoseman since I'm using DRF, how would I achieve this in the serializer ?

Comment: But now I don't understand what you want to do. I presumed you wanted to use this to display initial data in a form. But serializers don't have any concept of initial data. Under what circumstances would you display anything other than the current value of the field?

Comment: @DanielRoseman in the case that there is no value of the field entered, I would like to display a default value.
Each Form_33_Model has a corresponding html string, and certain values within that string should reflect whatever is entered inside `trademark_class` or `trademark_number` , this is all I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem in the end by overriding the `save()` method in the model.

```
class Form_33_Model(models.Model):
    trademark_number = models.CharField(default='default number', max_length=30)
    trademark_class = models.CharField(default='default class', max_length=30)
    trademark_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    html = models.TextField(default=Form33StringClass(
            trademark_class=trademark_class.get_default(),
            trademark_number=trademark_number.get_default()
            ).form_33_string)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.html = Form33StringClass(
                    trademark_class=self.trademark_class,
                    trademark_number=self.trademark_number
                    ).form_33_string
        super(Form_33_Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I still can't really understand what you are trying to do. But perhaps [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) is what you want?

```
class Form33ModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    html = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Form_33_Model

    def get_html(self, obj):
        return obj.html or obj._meta.get_field('trademark_class').get_default()
```

Comment: Pardon the speed of my replies, my ISP suddenly gave me poor service.
I have Edited my original question to try and show what I am trying to do.